# average of specific columns and storing them in new column

Tags: python, pandas, multiple-columns, mean

What am I doing wrong here? I have a dataframe where I am adding two new columns the first creates a count by adding all the values in each column to the right that are equal to 1. That part works fine. The next part of the code should give the average of all the values to the right that are not equal to 0. For some reason it is also taking the values to the left into account. Here is the code. Thanks for any help.

I have tried my code as well as both solutions below and am still getting the wrong average. Here's a simplified version with a random dataframe, and all three versions of the code. I have removed values to the left and still have the issue of the average being wrong. Maybe this will make help.

Version 1:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,3,size=(10, 10)), columns=list('ABCDEFGHIJ'))

idx_last = len(df.columns)
df.insert(loc=0, column='new', value=df[df[0:(idx_last+1)]==1].sum(axis=1))

idx_last = len(df.columns)
df.insert(loc=1, column='avg', value=df[df[0:(idx_last+1)]!=0].mean(axis=1))

df
```

Version 2:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,3,size=(10, 10)), columns=list('ABCDEFGHIJ'))

df.insert(loc=0, column='new', value=(df.iloc[:, 0:]==1).sum(axis=1))
df.insert(loc=1, column='avg', value=(df.iloc[:, 1:]!=0).mean(axis=1))

df
```

Version 3:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,3,size=(10, 10)), columns=list('ABCDEFGHIJ'))

idx_last = len(df.columns)
loc_value=0
df.insert(loc=loc_value, column='new', value=df[df[loc_value:(idx_last+1)]==1].sum(axis=1))

idx_last = len(df.columns)
loc_value=1
df.insert(loc=loc_value, column='avg', value=df[df[loc_value: (idx_last+1)]!=0].sum(axis=1))

df
```

Comment: sorry about that now I know better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) function for get columns by positions, because is added new column is necessary use position + 1 for `avg` column with [`DataFrame.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) for replace non matched values to missing values:

```
np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,3,size=(10, 5)), columns=list('ABCDE'))

df.insert(loc=0, column='new', value=(df.iloc[:, 0:]==1).sum(axis=1))
df.insert(loc=1, column='avg', value=(df.iloc[:, 1:].where(df.iloc[:, 1:]!=0)).mean(axis=1))
print (df)
   new       avg  A  B  C  D  E
0    1  1.750000  2  1  2  2  0
1    2  1.600000  2  2  1  2  1
2    2  1.500000  2  1  0  1  2
3    2  1.333333  1  0  2  0  1
4    1  1.500000  2  1  0  0  0
5    1  1.666667  0  1  2  0  2
6    2  1.000000  0  0  1  0  1
7    1  1.500000  0  0  0  2  1
8    2  1.600000  1  2  2  2  1
9    1  1.500000  0  0  2  1  0
```

Or use helper `DataFrame` in `df1` variable:

```
np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,3,size=(10, 5)), columns=list('ABCDE'))

df1 = df.copy()
df.insert(loc=0, column='new', value=(df1==1).sum(axis=1))
df.insert(loc=1, column='avg', value=df1.where(df1!=0).mean(axis=1))
print (df)
   new       avg  A  B  C  D  E
0    1  1.750000  2  1  2  2  0
1    2  1.600000  2  2  1  2  1
2    2  1.500000  2  1  0  1  2
3    2  1.333333  1  0  2  0  1
4    1  1.500000  2  1  0  0  0
5    1  1.666667  0  1  2  0  2
6    2  1.000000  0  0  1  0  1
7    1  1.500000  0  0  0  2  1
8    2  1.600000  1  2  2  2  1
9    1  1.500000  0  0  2  1  0
```

Comment: I couldn't get this to work. I've updated and simplified the question. Maybe you'll have some insight.

Comment: @rwa - Can you be more specific? If use `np.random.seed(123)` `df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,3,size=(10, 5)), columns=list('ABCDE'))` what is expected output?

Comment: ok I tried that and with your exact dataframe above I would expect the avg column to be this
1.75
1.60
1.50
1.33
1.50
1.67
1.00
1.50
1.60
1.50

Comment: that would be the average for the first row (2+1+2+2) = 7 and 7/4 = 1.75

Answer (score 2):

The issue arises with the expression,  `(df.iloc[:, 1:]!=0).mean(axis=1)`. It is because `df.iloc[:, 1:]!=0` will return a matrix of booleans, as it is a comparing expression. Taking a mean of such values will not give the mean of original values, as the maximum value in such matrix will anyway be 1.
Hence, the following would do the job (note the indexing as well)

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,3,size=(10, 10)), columns=list('ABCDEFGHIJ')) 
df.insert(loc=0, column='new', value=(df.iloc[:, 0:]==1).sum(axis=1)) 
df.insert(loc=1, column='avg', value=(df.iloc[:, 1:]!=0).sum(axis=1))  #just keeping the count of non zeros
df["avg"]=df.iloc[:, 2:].sum(axis=1)/df["avg"]
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. It really helps me see what I was doing wrong.